# Extract match by two column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

| ID | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 1 | 3 |
| AB | 0 | 1 |
| CD | 2 | 4 |
| CD | 2 | 3 |

I would like to compare row within each ID.
For each column with difference add in the mismatch referred to the column.

Output:

| ID | col1 | col2 | match_extract_col1 | match_extract_col2 | match_extract_col1_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 1 | 3 | Na | Na | 1:1 |
| AB | 0 | 1 | Na | Na | 1:1 |
| CD | 2 | 4 | 2:2 | Na | Na |
| CD | 2 | 3 | 2:2 | Na | Na |

For instance, I have a command like that to check only column by column :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(col1:col2, ~ if_else(n_distinct(.x) == 1, NA, toString(.x)),
                .names = "match_extract_{.col}"),
         .by = ID)
```

Comment: It is unclear. Can you explain what `match_extract_col1` and `match_extract_col2`, when should we expect NA, and when should we expect something else?

Comment: Are the ID's always in pairs or can there be more rows for any ID? Also why is col1 value of the second row suddenly changed from 1 to 0?

Comment: ID are always in pairs

Comment: the column match1 checks if there is a correspondence between the two lines AB for the col1 of the same for the col 2 and in the column match 1_2 one looks if there is an equality between the two lines in diagonals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

dt[, (c("match_extract_col1", "match_extract_col2")) := lapply(.SD, \(x) ifelse(length(unique(x)) == 1, paste(x, collapse = ":"), NA_character_)), by = ID, .SDcols = 2:3]
dt[, match_extract_col1_2 := ifelse(.SD[1, 1] == .SD[2, 2], paste(rep(.SD[1, 1], 2), collapse = ":"), NA_character_), by = ID, .SDcols = 2:3]
```

**results**

```
   ID col1 col2 match_extract_col1 match_extract_col2 match_extract_col1_2
1: AB    1    3               <NA>               <NA>                  1:1
2: AB    0    1               <NA>               <NA>                  1:1
3: CD    2    4                2:2               <NA>                 <NA>
4: CD    2    3                2:2               <NA>                 <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

If each ID has 2 rows, you can use `col1[1] == col2[2]` to check if the diagonal values are equal.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(col1:col2, ~ if_else(n_distinct(.x) == 1, paste(.x, collapse = ':'), NA),
                .names = "match_extract_{.col}"),
         match_extract_col1_2 = if_else(col1[1] == col2[2], paste(col1[1], col2[2], sep = ':'), NA),
         .by = ID)

#   ID col1 col2 match_extract_col1 match_extract_col2 match_extract_col1_2
# 1 AB    1    3               <NA>               <NA>                  1:1
# 2 AB    0    1               <NA>               <NA>                  1:1
# 3 CD    2    4                2:2               <NA>                 <NA>
# 4 CD    2    3                2:2               <NA>                 <NA>
```

---

Though I think it's redundant to format a match with `"x:y"`. If you call it a match, then `x` must be equal to `y`, so formatting a match with `"x"` is enough.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(col1:col2, ~ if_else(n_distinct(.x) == 1, .x[1], NA),
                .names = "match_extract_{.col}"),
         match_extract_col1_2 = if_else(col1[1] == col2[2], col1[1], NA),
         .by = ID)

#   ID col1 col2 match_extract_col1 match_extract_col2 match_extract_col1_2
# 1 AB    1    3                 NA                 NA                    1
# 2 AB    0    1                 NA                 NA                    1
# 3 CD    2    4                  2                 NA                   NA
# 4 CD    2    3                  2                 NA                   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` approach on a slightly modified data set.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(across(col1:col2, ~ if_else(.x == lag(.x) | .x == lead(.x), 
     paste0(.x, ":", .x), NA), .names="match_extract_{.col}"), 
         match_extract_col1_2 = 
           case_when(col1 == lead(col2) ~ paste0(col1,":",col1), 
                     col1 == lag(col2) ~ paste0(col1,":",col1))) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  ID     col1  col2 match_extract_col1 match_extract_col2 match_extract_col1_2
  <chr> <dbl> <int> <chr>              <chr>              <chr>               
1 AB        1     3 NA                 NA                 1:1                 
2 AB        3     1 NA                 NA                 3:3                 
3 CD        2     4 2:2                NA                 NA                  
4 CD        2     3 2:2                NA                 NA
```

##### mod. data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("AB", "AB", "CD", "CD"), col1 = c(1, 3, 
2, 2), col2 = c(3L, 1L, 4L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```