# Extract mismatch by ID

Tags: r

I have a table like that :

| ID | info1 | info2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01 | 02 |
| A | 11 | 02 |
| B | 01 | 02 |
| B | 10 | 20 |
| C | 03 | 02 |
| C | 01 | 04 |

I would like a result like that :

| ID | info1 | info2 | mismatch1+1 | mismatch 1+2 | mismatch1_2 | mismatch2+1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01 | 02 | 01:11 | 01:02 | 01:02 | 02:11 |
| A | 11 | 02 | 01:11 | 01:02 | 01:02 | 02:11 |
| B | 01 | 02 | 01:10 | 01:20 | 01:02 | 02:10 |
| B | 10 | 20 | 01:10 | 01:20 | 01:02 | 02:10 |
| C | 03 | 02 | 03:03 | 03:03 | 03:02 | 02:03 |
| C | 03 | 03 | 03:03 | 03:03 | 03:02 | 02:03 |

I tried that :

```
t <- t %>%
 arrange(`ID-COLT`)%>%
 mutate(across(A1:A2), 
        mismatch_extract_col1_2 = paste(A1[1], A1[2], sep = ":"),
        mismatch_extract_col1_1 = paste(A1[1], A2[1], sep = ":"),
        mismatch_extract_col2_2 = paste(A1[1], A2[2], sep = ":"),
        mismatch_extract_col2_1 =  paste(A2[1], A1[2], sep = ":"))
```

Thanks

Comment: You should try to explain better what you're trying to achieve. Your example is confusing

Comment: What mismatches are you trying to extract? what is the logic behind your expected output?

Comment: I want to extract all pairs for each ID

Comment: I want to compare row +1 column +1 and diagonal

Comment: Maybe try to transform the data to have the second line as 2 new columns that would be named info1_2 and info2_2. And from there you can make all the pairs with all the informations in the same observation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract match by two column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75518930/extract-match-by-two-column)

Answer (score 2):

Note I get this output only after adapting your data frame:

data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), info1 = c(1L, 
11L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 3L), info2 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 20L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("info"), ~sprintf("%02d", .))) %>% 
  mutate(`mismatch_1+1` = paste0(info1, collapse = ":"),
         `mismatch_1+2` = paste(info1[1], info2[2], sep = ":"),
         `mismatch1_2` =  paste(info1[1], info2[1], sep = ":"),
         `mismatch2+1` =  paste(info2[1], info1[2], sep = ":"))
```

```
  ID    info1 info2 `mismatch_1+1` `mismatch_1+2` mismatch1_2 `mismatch2+1`
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>          <chr>          <chr>       <chr>        
1 A     01    02    01:11          01:02          01:02       02:11        
2 A     11    02    01:11          01:02          01:02       02:11        
3 B     01    02    01:10          01:20          01:02       02:10        
4 B     10    20    01:10          01:20          01:02       02:10        
5 C     03    02    03:03          03:03          03:02       02:03        
6 C     03    03    03:03          03:03          03:02       02:03
```

Comment: I tried with your data frame and I have an error. A         1     2 1:11:1:10:3:3  1:2            1:2         2:11

Comment: Hmmh. I tested it again for me it works.

Comment: I always have the error.